# SharePoint 2010 Upgrade to SharePoint 2013 - Look and Feel did not Upgrade

Tags: sharepoint-server, master-page, upgrade, design-manager

I upgraded SharePoint 2010 to SharePoint 2013 but the look and feel did not upgrade and the site in SharePoint 2013 doesn't look anything like it does in SharePoint 2010.  Is there a way to export the look and feel from SharePoint 2010 and import into SharePoint 2013 or do I have to rebuild the look and feel from scratch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will manually re-brand the site.

Answer (score 0):

Have you also updated the site collection? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/upgrade-and-update/upgrade-a-site-collection-to-sharepoint-2013

Once you upgrade from SharePoint 2010, the sites will work in SharePoint 2013, but the look and feel won't be updated until you Upgrade the site collection. You can also do this through Powershell:

`Upgrade-SPSite http://server/sitecollection –VersionUpgrade`

Comment: Site collections have been upgraded.  It's missing page layout, banner icon, quick launch navigation, color scheme.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find if there is any compatibility issues, and resolve them prior UI upgrading

```
Test-SPSite http://SPWeb.Com/sites/siteCollection
```

2. Actual UI Upgrade

```
Upgrade-SPSite http://SPWeb.Com/sites/siteCollection –VersionUpgrade -Unthrottled 
 #Unthrottled flag starts upgrading immediately
```

3. Find the current upgrade status

```
Get-SPSiteUpgradeSessionInfo –site http://SPWeb.Com/sites/siteCollection
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the look after upgrade to SharePoint 2013, navigate to site settings->Site collection upgrade->click Upgrade this Site Collection.

Comment: Site collections have been upgraded.  It's missing page layout, banner icon, quick launch navigation, color scheme.  I believe I need to manually recreate the look and feel.